# Unable to catch Exception when passing null body with Content-Type:application/json

Tags: json, jersey, jax-rs

I've written an ExceptionMapper in order to catch all http exception (400,404,500,...) in my application.

```
    @Provider
    public class MyExceptionHandler implements ExceptionMapper<Exception> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Exception ex) {
        //Some Code to build Response
    }
```

unfortunately when I send a post request with Content-Type:application/json with empty or wrong format body, this error occurs and I can not catch it in MyExceptionHandler.

```
Status Code: 400 Bad Request

No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@5774bb5e; line: 1, column: 1]
```

what did I do wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Environment: JAX-RS, GlassFish 3

Edit:
I think this error is related to AppServer and must be handled there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there is a bad request such as wrong format body, the `WebApplicationException` is thrown. Here is how exception mappers are selected

- When a WebApplicationException, or one of its subclasses, with an
  empty entity body is thrown, the runtime will check to see if there
  is an exception mapper that handles WebApplicationException
  exceptions. If there is the exception mapper is used to create the
  response sent to the consumer.
- When any exception other than a WebApplicationException exception, or
  one of its subclasses, is thrown, the runtime will check for an
  appropriate exception mapper. An exception mapper is selected if it
  handles the specific exception thrown. If there is not an exception
  mapper for the specific exception that was thrown, the exception
  mapper for the nearest superclass of the exception is selected.

Here is what I would recommend

- register an `ExceptionMapper<WebApplicationException>`
- register an `ExceptionMapper<Throwable>` to catch all other exceptions with a generic response signaling a 500 sever error.

Comment: Thank You for the answer. I tried both of them and any of these exception handlers couldn't catch the '400 Bad Request'. Any idea?